# What about this reviewed rejection?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8786909) review which was rejected by one of the reviewer and he actually did "Reject and Edit" which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31393843/revisions). In his edit he did the same thing except I had removed some unnecessary words and a highlighting.

What is the main reason to be rejected in this case?

Is it for being under 2k?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - you suggested a perfectly good edit, and the "improved" version was worse. Sometimes it just happens - reviewers aren't always correct.

Comment: Your edit was right.May be @erisco can explain why he choose 'Reject and Edit'.

Comment: one question what did you mean by `Is it for being under 2k?`?

Comment: I had a look on several questions and answers on post edits and related topics before and concluded that "there are some edits which should be rejected for under 2k users, because they would get 2+ reputation for an edit. Example: Just removing 'Thanks'. But it is not bad for 2k or more reputation gainers". So, I just wanted to know that is it one of them or not. @ShaifulIslam

Comment: I think that may be one of the reason or did not paid enough attention.But your edit was better than him. I made another edit.

Comment: I have changed the title of the question. @shaifulislam

Comment: You might misunderstand erisco. He felt guilty and said, **I don't know why I rejected instead of improved. Maybe the "improve" option didn't show up or I did not understand the difference at the time.** However, you have right to do whatever you want. Just remember, you are the only one in this post who supported erisco's work fully which erisco himself did not support later. @richardlemesurier

Comment: Okay, though his comments are parts of his answer as things are cleared better in comments and these express his last point of view. Another point is that I never said that erisco told it (erisco's speech quoted in my last comment) "in his answer", rather the matter of misunderstanding is to just only considering "his answer", not "his comment". However, I don't want to argue with you on such useless topic. Victory is yours! Enjoy! @richardlemesurier

Comment: Can you please describe me the reason of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8854383) rejection?@ShaifulIslam

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the main reason to be rejected in this case?

I don't know why the user rejected your edit. Your edit was good and like you said better than his. It was probably just a mistake on his part.

I wouldn't worry about this happening just once or twice. If for some reason you feel like investigating a user who rejected your edit, you can just go to their profile, and search through their suggested edit reviews. If you find a user doing incorrect reviews like this often then just flag one of the user's posts for custom moderator flag and explain that the user is incorrectly doing reviews and provide links to some of those reviews. I didn't find anything suspicious in this user's case.

Comment: To do a better review in future, I think @erisco has the right to know that his review was a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

I go through my edit queue occasionally and maybe my standards are outdated or maybe I am applying extra criteria.

I did not agree with a few of the edits you made because they were minor or frivolous, and to that extent I do not consider it kind to reword other people's questions just for the sake of it.

Moving the image to the next line did not accomplish much. Maybe it is a bit unsightly with the alignment of the adjacent text, that I will agree. Nonetheless it was still readable and the line was not too long.

Removing the extra indentation in the code example was an improvement because it shortened the horizontal scrolling, so I kept that.

Changing "I want to somehow fix this control" to "I want to fix this control somehow" is a useless edit. From my perspective this is Laziale's question and they have taken their own care and time to write it up. If there are spelling or grammar mistakes that is one thing, but swapping some words around to give the same meaning is something else.

Changing 'Browse' to **Browse** again I find pointless. There is nothing wrong that I can tell with quoting the word 'Browse' to indicate the syntax rather than the semantic. The latest edit that replaces 'Browse' with a button graphic is a neat feature that I was not aware of.

I did mean to nuke the trailer "Thanks in advance, Laziale" as you had done. That is my bad for missing it.

Comment: While I disagree with your point about moving the image to a new line, (It makes the question look less cluttered and more properly formatted to have it on a new line, after all.) I can certainly see, and agree with, your other two issues with the OP's suggested edit. My question, however: If there were really only a couple really small issues with the edit, why did you find "Reject and Edit" a better option than "Improve" for this particular scenario?

Comment: Keeping the image at its previous position does not look good as  the image looks like superscript of the line "I have this file upload control:". See the newest revision.
To me "I want to fix this control somehow" is more realizable as the flow of the concentration ends first here.
I tried to give the word Browse more feeling of a button. In a button, the writings does not contain quotation usually, so 'Browse' looks a little bit odd to me.
However, I might have mistake, but I think, I did not do anything to be `rejected`!

Comment: I don't know why I rejected instead of improved. Maybe the "improve" option didn't show up or I did not understand the difference at the time. The UI was confusing me. If it is any consolation I have awarded you 10 points on both Meta and Stackoverflow.

Comment: It is not a matter of points. Your clarification and opinion is the main matter. no matter of consolation here! @erisco

Comment: @manetsus I wouldn't be too bothered by all of this- Erisco at least took the time to outline exactly what they felt wrong with your edit and why. They had absolutely no reason why they had to, so it's great that they did. In the end, the important changes got made, and that's what matters. From the sounds of it, had the UI not confused them, it probably would've been an "Improve" selection instead of a "Reject and Edit" for this. Learning moment for both involved, and the SO question looks better than it did.

Comment: @manetsus Also, regarding _"However, I might have mistake, but I think, I did not do anything to be `rejected!`"_ Much like an asker who sees nothing wrong with a question that is off-topic for the site, an editor may very well have a hard time seeing what was wrong with their edit, even with presented with it. (Just human nature.) After all, if you made the edit, clearly you thought the edit was a great idea and should be accepted. In this case, the edit probably should've been "Improved" rather than rejected, but if the UI threw Erisco off, and I can see how it may have, then it happens.

Comment: @kendra there was discussion a while back where it was concluded to "teach" new users not to do minor edits, by using the reject & edit functionality. While I disagree with the idea that you can "teach" in this way, it seems to have been the site consensus at the time.

Comment: @erisco Are you admitting to serial upvoting?